# Reusing ID string for View elements in xml layout

Tags: java, android

I've got an app that has a handheld layout.xml and a tablet layout.xml.  Inside the layout.xml a fragment is declared like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:paddingTop="2dp"
              android:paddingBottom="2dp">

<fragment class="com.example.MyFrag"
          android:id="@+id/myFrag"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For the same of keeping things simple, let's say that this layout.xml is identical in res/layout and res/layout-large.

In my main activity, I reference this fragment like this:

```
final myFrag = (MyFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFrag);
```

This works fine for the tablet, but when I try to run on handheld, myFrag is null.  After a little playing around I found that if I change the name in the handheld layout.xml to myFrag2 and search for that name instead, it works.  What confuses me is that according to the Android documentation, I should be able to reuse this id:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id

Am I doing something wrong?  I really don't want to have to write code to test whether myFrag is null and then try loading the handheld name instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a non-question.  I couldnt say exactly why but it appears R was not being properly regenerated.  I wiped it out and regenerated it and all was well with the world, so it looks like there's nothing special going on afterall.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know if you will be using the res/layout-large then you must not use the res/layout default directory for a layout. So if you will be using screen sizes then you should use all (most) that you will be considering. So you will need to implement small, normal for handhelds.
you can read the documentation regarding screen sizes [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)

Comment: I couldnt find any explicit mention of this rule in the documentation.  My assumption was that if I did not provide an explicit resource for a given size, then it would default to what was in res/layout, which appears to be the case.  I used a simplistic example to illustrate the question above, but I have quite a few other resources that dont have overlapping fragment id's which appear to work without issue so I'm a little skeptical.